# Firebase Function onLink trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to implement a function hook on when an anonymous user is linked to a normal account?

What I am trying to achieve in a secure way is:

---

**1.** DeepLink for invitation opens in the app.
**2.** Get `invited_by` from the URL and sign in the user anonymously, saving `invited_by` to `invitations/anonymous_user_1/invited_by`.
**3.** User registers an account and signs in so `onCreate` function is triggered, but we do not have access to the anonymous account there.
**4.** If there already is an anonymous account before registering, we link the anonymous account to the users new account.

---

And here is where I want to trigger a remote firebase function (don't want to trigger it on the client side, because it could be retriggered and abused to gain invitation advantages).

`onLink()` should do something like this:

---

**1.** Get old account (anonymous) and new account.
**2.** Get `invitations/anonymous_user_1/invited_by` from anonymous account.
**3.** Store it and perform actions on the new account.
**4.** Delete `invitations/anonymous_user_1/invited_by` once processed.

---

Is there a way to do this server side? Because `onLink()` would only be called once, and therefore I could process the anonymous data once.
As I said I would not want to call a function locally.

Thanks

Comment: You're describing functionality that doesn't exist today.  If you have a feature request, please file it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I did that, and I also thought about a secure alternative to my problem and will use that now :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Firebase Authentication trigger for Cloud Functions when a user links accounts from multiple providers at the moment. As Doug commented, it's best to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for this.